# Using multiple string resources for different textviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

Hey, I'm currently having trouble with a small Android application I'm making. What I'm attempting to build is:

- A list interface with

  - Each row having two TextViews (a title and a caption).
  - Have the values of these to be drawn from two separate string array resources.

The interface has the following text views in `rowLayout.xml`,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:text="@+id/rowTitle"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:textSize="25px"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
</TextView>

<TextView android:text="@+id/rowCaption"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/caption"
          android:textSize="25px"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
</TextView>
```

and the string resources are,

```
<string-array name="menuEntryTitles">
    <item>Start</item>
    <item>Stop</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="menuEntryCaptions">
    <item>Starts the update listener service.</item>
    <item>Stops the update listener service.</item>
</string-array>
```

There should be two rows titled Start and Stop and each has their relevant captions. I've attempted using an `ArrayAdapter` to implement this,

```
ArrayAdapter listAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
             new int[] {R.array.menuEntryTitles, R.array.menuEntryCaptions},
             new int[] {R.id.rowTitle, R.id.rowCaption});
```

but I'm getting errors due to `createFromResource` requiring `int` arguments when I can only provide `int[]`.

Hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create your own adapter since ArrayAdapter only uses one array, and not two.

You can create the adapter as a private class within you ListActivity. Try something like this (warning: code not tested):

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected void onCreate(){

        ....

        // Get arrays from resources
        Resources r = getResources();    
        String [] arr1 = r.getStringArray("menuEntryTitles");
        String [] arr1 = r.getStringArray("menuEntryCaptions");

        // Create your adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(arr1, arr2);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        String [] arr1;
        String [] arr2;

        public MyAdapter(String[] arr1, String[] arr2){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)MyListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            this.arr1 = arr1;
            this.arr2 = arr2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arr1.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Used to keep references to your views, optimizes scrolling in list
        private static class ViewHolder {
             TextView tv1;
             TextView tv2;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
                holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowCaption);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.tv1.setText(arr1[position]);
            holder.tv2.setText(arr2[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `<Track>` and `tracks` are used for?

Comment: Sorry, but the code related to Track was a copy-paste error from my side. I have removed it now. Have you tested the code? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Gave it a go and got a force close error on start up. A few debug runs later and I managed to get it working just nicely :). Eclipse complained about some of the overrides which had to be removed to run.  Now to study the code a bit to get my head around what's being done to display these items. Thank you very much.